# Can't stop movie playback immediately

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When you launch a video and IMMEDIATELY press "Done" the MPMoviePlayerController will exit, however the video still plays in the background (you can hear the audio).  It works fine if you allow the video to begin playing before you hit the "Done" button.

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:  This seems to be a known 3.0 bug.  I was unable to find a workaround

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development-advanced-discussion/15768-mpmovieplayer-video-via-url-glitch.html

Comment: Update: if you follow this link now somebody seems to have found a solution at the bottom.

Comment: hello sam. i am doing the same code what you have used. But i am having some issue,like when i play video using MPMoviePlayerController and press home button,my app goes into background and video is paused somehow. I need to know what is supposed to be done for not pausing state. I want to make it playing  in background mode continuously. i hope you may help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling stop on your MPMoviePlayerController instance when the view controller that spawned the movie receives its viewDidAppear: (or viewWillAppear:) methods

Comment: The player is already stopped and is released correctly. stop causes the window to go away, which does happen.

I have tried the nasty approach of using class dump functions to try and pause on start then resume when receiving _playStateDidChange but this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

While, so far, I've also found MPMoviePlayerController somewhat erratic, I imagine just releasing the object (after listening to a MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification) would help.